# How to clear Gutenberg (Redux) Store with an interval

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have crated a custom store based on the [official guideline](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/) and it's working just fine. Since the data in the database changes in a certain interval I like to refetch the data in a given time.

This is how I get the data using `useSelect` and a custom action `getData`

```js
const data = useSelect((select) =>
    select(MY_CUSTOM_STORE).getData();
);
```

I like to change the data once a constant `my_constant` changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    clearData();
}, [my_constant]);
```

So how should the `clearData` method look like?

Not sure if `setInterval` can be used as the data changes frequently.